# Spring boot batch partitioning JdbcCursorItemReader error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, partitioning

I have been unable to get this to work even after following [Victor Jabor blog](https://victorjabur.com/2014/11/10/spring-batch-partitioner-case-study-with-sourcecode-best-practices/) very comprehensive example. I have followed his configuration as he described and used all the latest dependencies. I, as Victor am trying to read from one db and write to another. I have this working without partitioning but need partitioning to improve performance as I need to be able to read 5 to 10 million rows within 5mins.

The following seems to work:
1) ColumnRangePartitioner
2) TaskExecutorPartitionHandler builds the correct number of step tasks based on the gridsize and spawns the correct number of threads
3) setPreparedStatementSetter from the stepExecution set by the ColumnRangePartitioner.

But when I run the application I get errors from JdbcCursorItemReader which are not consistent and which I dont understand. As a last resort I will have to debug the JdbcCursorItemReader. I am hoping to get some help before this and hopefully it will be a configuration issue.

> ERROR:
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:901) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(JdbcUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.getColumnValue(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:370) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:291) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.readCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:139) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]

Configuration classes:

```
@Configuration @EnableBatchProcessing public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Archive, Archive> processor(@Value("${etl.region}") String region) {
        return new ArchiveProcessor(region);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Archive> writer(@Qualifier(value = "postgres") DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Archive> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();

        writer.setSql("insert into tdw_src.archive (id) " +
                "values (:id)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new org.springframework.batch.item.database.
                BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Partitioner archivePartitioner(@Qualifier(value = "gmDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                          @Value("ROWNUM") String column,
                                          @Value("archive") String table,
                                          @Value("${gm.datasource.username}") String schema) {
        return new ColumnRangePartitioner(dataSource, column, schema + "." + table);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job archiveJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step partitionerStep, JobExecutionListener listener) {
        return jobs.get("archiveJob")
                .preventRestart()
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(partitionerStep)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step partitionerStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                Partitioner archivePartitioner,
                                Step step1,
                                @Value("${spring.batch.gridsize}") int gridSize) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionerStep")
                .partitioner(step1)
                .partitioner("step1", archivePartitioner)
                .gridSize(gridSize)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "step1")
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Archive> customReader,
                      ItemWriter<Archive> writer, ItemProcessor<Archive, Archive> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .listener(customReader)
                .<Archive, Archive>chunk(5)
                .reader(customReader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher getJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

Custom Reader:-

public class CustomReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<Archive> implements StepExecutionListener {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Autowired
    public CustomReader(@Qualifier(value = "gmDataSource") DataSource geomangerDataSource,
                        @Value("${gm.datasource.username}") String schema) throws Exception {
        super();
        this.setSql("SELECT TMP.* FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS ID_PAGINATION, id FROM " + schema + ".archive) TMP " +
                "WHERE TMP.ID_PAGINATION >= ? AND TMP.ID_PAGINATION <= ?");
        this.setDataSource(geomangerDataSource);
        BeanPropertyRowMapper<Archive> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Archive.class);
        this.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
        this.setFetchSize(5);
        this.setSaveState(false);

        this.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
// not sure if this is needed?       this.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
        this.setPreparedStatementSetter(getPreparedStatementSetter());
    }

    private PreparedStatementSetter getPreparedStatementSetter() {
        ListPreparedStatementSetter listPreparedStatementSetter = new ListPreparedStatementSetter();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("minValue"));
        list.add(stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getInt("maxValue"));
        listPreparedStatementSetter.setParameters(list);
        LOGGER.debug("getPreparedStatementSetter list: " + list);
        return listPreparedStatementSetter;
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed Customer reader as a Component and added to Batch config the following:     @Bean
    public ItemReader<Archive> reader(@Qualifier(value = "gmDataSource") DataSource geomangerDataSource,
                                      @Value("${geomanager.datasource.username}") String schema) throws Exception {

        return new CustomReader(geomangerDataSource, schema);
    }

Still getting the same error:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1381) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]

Answer (score 0):

I've got this all working.

First I needed to order my select statement in my CustomReader so the rownum remains the same for all threads and lastly I had to scope the beans by using @StepScope for each bean used in the step.

In reality I wont be using rownum since this needs to be ordered which reduce loose performance and therefore I will use a pk column to get the best performance.